# I have requirement to generate HTML to PDF and save the PDF to SharePoint Document Library using Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

We have one requirement where we need to generate HTML to PDF and store it on document Library.
So far we are able to generate the HTML to PDF but not able to store it in SharePoint Document Library.

Note: we are using kendo plugin for PDF conversion, Kendo giving SaveAs option to save the PDF locally, our requirement to store the PDF in SharePoint Environment.

Code Snipped:
kendo.drawing.pdf.saveAs(“PDFName”)

If anyone did similar requirement in past Please revert back to me.
We are Interested to achieve the solution with Client side programming. MS flow is not in scope as of now.

Comment: This looks like homework. Could you share what you tried so far, what is blocking you, how you tried to overcome it?

Answer (score 0):

You could upload the file to sharepoint library via rest api:

- [create a file and add it to a folder.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/working-with-folders-and-files-with-rest#working-with-files-by-using-rest)

And below is a sample:
[How to Upload File in Document Library in SharePoint Using REST API & jQuery](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/91b369/how-to-upload-file-in-document-library-in-sharepoint-using-r/)